# xDB Migration Tool: "Specify the name of the connection string for the xConnect client service."

Tags: xdb, data-migration

I am populating the "xConnect Client Endpoint", path:

`/sitecore/system/Data Exchange/xDB Data Migration 8x to 9 Branch/Endpoints/Providers/xConnect/xConnect Client Endpoint`

The guide mentions,

"In the Collection Service Connection String Name field, specify the name of the connection stringfor the xConnect client service."

What connection does it refers to? If I use "xconnect.collection" (default connection string) that it points to "https://XPScaled910.search" I get the following message when I run the Troubleshooter:

"Exception was thrown. Read more in log file. An error occurred while sending the request."

**Question**

What value should I put under "Collection Service Connection String Name"

**Bonus Question**

If I'm using the right connection string, why would I be getting that error message? There is nothing in the Sitecore log.

Answer (score 1):

You need the name of your collection connection string

[image]

Comment: Cool, those are the right ones then. Any help with the Bonus Question?

Comment: The url https://XPScaled910.search does not seem right. It would be your xconnect url. Does your xconnect work?

Comment: When I open that URL on Edge, I see a timer, something lke "0:36:20.2572836" in the page. If I open the URL on Brave/Chrome, I get a 403.16 due to the self-signed certificate.

What am I supposed to see there?

Comment: This all on one server or several?

Comment: I'm confused - which other servers should I check? For what?

Comment: Oh, now I get it - everything is on the same server, it's a dev environment.